# Bootstrap 3 - DateTimePicker - Can time portion be ignored?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I'm using the Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker. When the user tabs into a field using this component, the current date and time is automatically entered. In some cases this is what I want. However, there are other times I want the component to completely ignore the time portion and not entered by default in a field. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: which datetimepicker? any code or specific url?

Comment: There is only one Bootstrap datetimepicker that I'm aware of - http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only display the date by default, try and see

```
            $('.future');.datetimepicker({
                pickTime: false,
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            });
```

Comment: "pickTime" is no more available. Using "format" is enough.